# Vuex Mutation return last inserted

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I want to return a value from mutation to action.
I this case, I want the last inserted object :

In my mutation, work fine :

```
mutations: {
  insert(state, item) {
    const guid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; // any sense, just example
    item.guid = guid;
    state.data.push(item);
    return guid;
  },
},
```

In my action, work fine for the call, not for the return :

```
actions: {
  insert ({ commit }, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const guid = commit('insert', event);
      resolve(guid); // resolve undefined
    });
  },
},
```

There is a way to return the guid ?
I need it to emit after with my component...

Thanks

Comment: Though this doesn't exactly answer your question, I think the common practice is to avoid generating data in the mutation. Your action would then have the GUID and pass it to the mutation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mutations (commits) **don't** return values](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/v3.0.1/src/store.js#L104).

And, as mentioned in comments, the best practice is to leave such GUID *generation* computation to an action and just really *commit* the state in the mutation.

That being said, you cand send a callback to the mutation and call it. Just make sure the callback code is simple and synchronous (if not, see below).

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
strict: true,
  state: {
    data: []
  },
  mutations: {
    insert(state, {item, callback}) {
      const guid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 600) + 1; // any sense, just example
      item.guid = guid;
      state.data.push(item);
      callback(guid);
    },
  },
  actions: {
    insert ({ commit }, data) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        commit('insert', {item: data, callback: resolve});
      });
    },
  },
});

new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
  data: { insertedGuid: 'click button below' },
  methods: {
   go: async function() {
      const guid = await this.$store.dispatch('insert', {name: "Alice"});
      this.insertedGuid = guid;
   }
 },
  computed: {
    datadata: function() {
      return this.$store.state.data
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>store's data: {{ datadata }}</p>
  <p>insertedGuid: {{ insertedGuid }}</p>
  <button @click="go">Click to Insert</button>
</div>
```

If you have no idea of what the callback could be, I suggest you wrap it as

```
setTimeout(() => callback(guid));
```

Which would end the mutation right away and send the callback execution later down the queue of the event loop.

Comment: Absolutely that ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can access the state data by passing it into the action  `insert ({ commit, state }, data) { ...`

example:

```
actions: {
  insert ({ commit, state }, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      commit('insert', event);
      const guid = state.data[state.data.length].guid
      resolve(guid); // resolve undefined
    });
  },
},
```